# VBA to delete command button in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

The same question on this site provides the following code to delete a command button in a Word document:

```
Dim o As Object
For Each o In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
If o.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "Test" Then
o.Delete
End If
Next
```

This worked fine for a few days, but now I get an 'Object variable or With block variable not set' error.

No doubt it is something obvious. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add another InlineShape which isn't a command button?